# I am not able to update date in MySQL version 8.0

Tags: mysql, sql-update

```
> select * from temp2;

+------------+-----+
|     to     | id  |
+------------+-----+
| 2020-08-10 | 222 |
| 2020-08-12 | 223 |
+------------+-----+
```

Here 'to' is of type date and 'id' is of varchar.

```
UPDATE temp2 SET to= '2020-07-12'  where id ='222' ;

UPDATE temp2 SET to= '2014-03-16 00:00:00.000'  where id='123';
```

None of these lines working It is showing error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to= '2014-03-16 00:00:00.000'  where id=123' at line 1
```

Comment: Enclose `to` inside backticks.

Comment: `to` is a reserved word in MySql.

Comment: yes i get it now i have wasted more than an hour on this ...thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
UPDATE temp2 SET `to` = '2020-07-12'  where `id` ='222' ;

UPDATE temp2 SET `to` = '2014-03-16 00:00:00.000' where `id` ='123';
```

backticks ` are used around the columns names

Comment: @AbhishekRathore Also not sure if the second query will work, because the `to` field seems to have a type: date, and the second query is setting giving It a timestamp ('2014-03-16 00:00:00.000'). Not entirely sure but this may be also a problem if there are still issues with the second query

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
UPDATE temp2 SET `to` = '2020-07-12'  where id ='222'
```

the column to is wrapped in backtick operator, this happens when you use one of the mysql keyword as your table column name.

Best practice to avoid such column names. but if you need to used it, then always used it with backtick.